# error al mostrar una variable - ERROR TypeError: "ctx.event.user is undefined"

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo una pagina web con un frontend en Angular y un backend con Symfony, de momento estoy utilizando como servidor xampp. 
Todo funcionaba de maravilla pero de repente, al iniciar el proyecto esta mañana me ha saltado un error por la consola del navegador

> ERROR TypeError: "ctx.event.user is undefined"
>           EventDetailComponent_Template event-detail.component.html:2
>           Angular 23
>           RxJS 5
>           Angular 8
>       core.js:6189:19
>           Angular 15
>           RxJS 5
>           Angular 8

En cuanto al compilador de ng serve de Angular tambien

> ERROR in
>   src/app/components/event-detail/event-detail.component.html:2:7 -
>   error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Event'.>
>   2
>
> {{event.user.name}}
>
> src/app/components/event-detail/event-detail.component.ts:13:16
>   13   templateUrl: './event-detail.component.html',
>   Error occurs in the template of component EventDetailComponent.

El problema está en que el código funciona correctamente ya que uso exactamente lo mismo en otro componente y no tengo ningún fallo. 
Como pone que no se encuentra la variable de **event.user** he decidido hacer una `console.log(event)` para ver si realmente no están llegando bien los datos, pero al verificarlo, todos los datos llegan correctamente pero es como si no los detectase.

Hace relativamente poco que he empezado a utilizar `Angular` y no se como seguir, estoy muy atascado ahora mismo.

Este es mi component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { Event } from '../../models/event';
import { EventService } from '../../services/event.service';

import { ViewChild, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-detail',
  templateUrl: './event-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-detail.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService, EventService]
})
export class EventDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public status;
  public identity;
  public token;
  public event: Event;


  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _eventService: EventService,

  ) { 
    this.identity = this._userService.getIdentity();
    this.token = this._userService.getToken();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.event = new Event(1, this.identity.sub, '', null, '', '', '','','', null, null);
    this.getEvento();

  }

  getEvento(){
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var id = +params['id'];

      this._eventService.getEvent(this.token, id).subscribe(
        response => {
          if(response.status == 'success') {
            this.event = response.event;
          }else{
            this._router.navigate(['/mis-eventos']);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.status = error;

        }
      );
    });
  }           
}
```

Y en el component.html lo llamo poniendo

```
<p>{{event.user.name}}<p>
```

edit: Aqui dejo el console.log(response) donde se ve claramente que la variable que pone que no esta definida existe y tiene los datos que necesito. Se me ha olvidado mencionar que los datos se ven por pantalla, pero el error sigue saliendo.

[image: Json de respuesta]

Comment: puedes hacer log de `response` en el subscribe?

Comment: `Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Event'` es muy claro el mensaje, la propiedad user no existe en el tipo `Event`, verifica tu interfaz / modelo

Comment: Pero no tiene sentido porque si existe y los datos llegan correctamente. Además que uso exactamente el mismo método en otro componente y funciona todo.

Comment: @Sr.Cocis podés mostrar la definición de  `Event` por favor. Por lo que veo está en `'../../models/event'`

Comment: Hola, lo que puedo entender es al iniciar la por primera ves del lado del HTML esta intentando leer una variable que aun no esta definida en este caso event si existe pero lo siguiente es user que para el aun no existe esto lo puedes arreglas colocando esto (?) {{event?.user.name}} en una de las ultimas actualizaciones de typescript agregaron la función de poder hacer una validación de la propiedades de un objeto si existen o no agregando el signo ?.

Comment: @hawks he editado la pregunta con el console.log(response). Además dentro de la funcion ngOnit(), despues de justo la funcion que en teoria tiene que coger el evento,he hecho un console.log(this.event) y para mi sorpresa esta vacio. Supongo que aqui esta el problema, pero es muy raro, la funcion de getEvento() deberia hacer su trabajo y rellenar el evento.

Comment: @AndresAbadia he intentado hacer lo que me dices, pero, sigue saliendo el error. Tambien he intentado hacer un *ngIf="event" dentro de la cabecera del div, cosa que funciona y ya no me sale el error en la consola del navegador, pero en la del compilador sigue ahí....

Comment: @NeryOrtez es esta: 
'export class Event{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public user_id: number,
        public url: string,
        public createdAt: any,
        public status: string,
        public title: string,
        public description: string,
        public price: string,
        public date: string,
        public latitude: number,
        public longitude: number,
    ){}
}' 
Como digo, esta clase la uso en otras partes del codigo de la misma manera y funciona bien, no creo que el error esté aquí.

Comment: No te preocupes, es una tonteria como un castillo. El problema es que cuando el navegador llega a donde tiene que pintar los datos que tienes, estos tardan en llegar una decima de segundo más, por lo que aparece error en la consola aunque la página funciona. Estás utilizando promesas? Por que si es así la solución es muy sencilla. Solo tendrías que colocar interrogación en las llamadas de los datos, es decir, en lugar de llamar a un dato "proyecto.titulo" deberias llamarlo "proyecto?.titulo" y de esa forma haces al navegador esperar ese contenido y que vaya pintando las cosas según las va reci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo por el error que te da, en el `ngOnInit` cuando inicializas la variable `event` no estarás seteando la propiedad `user` o si que la seteas pero es `undefined`.

Hay dos soluciones:

1. Setear la propiedad `user` en `this.event` como `{}`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // en la clase Event deberias crear la propiedad user sino la tienes
    this.event = new Event(1, this.identity.sub, '', null, '', '', '','','', null, null);
    this.event.user = {};
    this.getEvento();
}
```

2. En la template usar el safe navigation operator de angular `?.` Que comprueba si existe la propieda pues renderiza sino nada.

```
<p>{{event?.user?.name}}<p>
```

Comment: He hecho esto, y además he seteado el user como {} y se me han quitado los errores! Muchas gracias.